# How does FTP protocol negotiate SSL connection?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ftp, network-programming

I have read the RFC and am trying to implement an SSL connection in my FTP Server.

I have switched all of my Sockets to SSLServer Sockets and SSLsockets using javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

When using FileZilla to use SSL explicit encryption, I get a message saying, 
"Connected with 127.0.0.1, negotiating SSL connection"

and it would be stuck there.

How do I program my server to negotiate the SSL connection?

This code below is where the ServerSocket is started and waits for connections.

```
// Starts a server Socket to listen to new clients
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","ServerFiles\\default_KeyStore\\server.keystore");
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        this.entryPortSock = (SSLServerSocket)sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket((Integer) st.getValue("CMDPort"));
        SSLSocket scCMDPort;

        // Initiates the Rolling Log
        RollingLog rollingLog = new RollingLog((String) st.getValue("LOGfiledirectory"), st);
        Runnable RunnableRollingLog = rollingLog;
        Thread logger = new Thread(RunnableRollingLog);
        logger.start();

        // Continues to listen to new clients and connect to them when
        // available.
        while (true) {
            scCMDPort =(SSLSocket) this.entryPortSock.accept();
            System.out.println("System accepted a new friend!");

            // Starting the service for the client
            Runnable ftpService = new FTPService(rollingLog, (String) st.getValue("ROOT"), scCMDPort, st);
            Thread service = new Thread(ftpService);
            service.start();
        }
```

This below is the supported commands of my Server that it can accept from the client.

```
 private void action(ServerCmd command) {
    // Process of logging in, Must pass this boundary before any other
    // command can be given.

    if (DEBUG_INCOMING) {
        System.out.println("Client: " + command.cmdType + " " + reJoinString(command.args));
    }
    printLog("Client: " + command.cmdType + " " + reJoinString(command.args));

    if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.AUTH)) {
        if(command.args.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("SSL")){


            this.sendOut("334 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!");
        }
    }
    else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.USER)) {
        this.User(command);
    }

    else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.PASS)) {
        this.Pass(command.args.get(0));
    }

    // After login in, all of these commands can be read.
    else if (this.Status == 1) {
        if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.SYST)) {
            // Reads a request for the operating system of the Server.
            this.Syst();
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.FEAT)) {
            // Reads a request FEAT
            this.Feat();
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.PWD)) {
            // Reads a request to print the working directory
            this.Pwd();
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.TYPE)) {
            // Read a request Type
            this.Type(command.args.get(0));
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.PASV)) {
            // Request PASV connection
            this.Pasv();
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.LIST)) {
            // Request directory listing
            this.List();
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.CWD)) {
            //
            String temp = this.reJoinString((command.args));
            this.Cwd(temp);
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.CDUP)) {
            this.Cdup();
        }

        else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.STOR)) {
            this.Stor(this.reJoinString(command.args));
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.RETR)) {
            this.Retr(this.reJoinString(command.args));
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.QUIT)) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.HELP)) {
            sendOut("214 Help: Connect to FileZilla, the older version without caching to use this FTP Server. Or, a command prompt client would work as well.\n"
                    + "Accepted FTP Commands: USER, PASS, SYST, FEAT, PWD, TYPE, PASV, LIST, CWD, CDUP, EPSV, STOR, RETR, QUIT");
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals((ServerCommands.PORT))) {
            if (((String) (this.settings.getValue("PORTmode"))).equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                this.Port(this.reJoinString(command.args));
            } else {
                sendOut("522 This command is not supported");
            }
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals(ServerCommands.EPRT)) {
            if (((String) (this.settings.getValue("PORTmode"))).equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                this.EPRT(this.reJoinString(command.args));
            } else {
                sendOut("522 This command is not supported");
            }
        } else if (command.cmdType.equals((ServerCommands.EPSV))) {
            // Turn true to support EPSV
            if (((String) (this.settings.getValue("PASVmode"))).equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                this.EPSV();
            } else {
                sendOut("522 This command is not supported");
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
I implemented an upgrade from Socket to SSL socket once the AUTH SSL command has been sent from the client. Here is my code:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            this.clientSocket1 = sslsocketfactory.createSocket(serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            ((SSLSocket)this.clientSocket1).setUseClientMode(false);
            this.sendOut("334 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!");
```

The client response with this: Client: €j Q  [] 9 8 5 [] []
something like that. How do I decrypt the message?

To try to respond to the problem above, I re instantiated my in buffer reader that was reading from the regular Socket to the stream from the SSLSocket with the following code below:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            this.clientSocket1 = sslsocketfactory.createSocket(serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            ((SSLSocket)this.clientSocket1).setUseClientMode(false);
            ((SSLSocket)this.clientSocket1).startHandshake();
            cipher  =sslsocketfactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
            this.encrypted = true;
            this.sendOut("334 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!");
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((SSLSocket)this.clientSocket1).getInputStream()));
            this.out = new PrintWriter(((SSLSocket)this.clientSocket1).getOutputStream());
```

Entire Stack trace of possible handshaking crash.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at FTPServer.FTPService.run(FTPService.java:100)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The Client's Log: <--- file zilla
Response:   220 IiiiDeentiffy YouuurSelf!!!
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   234 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!

The Server's Log <--- the one I am programming

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at FTPServer.FTPService.run(FTPService.java:100)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext     connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(Unknown Source)
at FTPServer.FTPService.action(FTPService.java:143)
at FTPServer.FTPService.run(FTPService.java:102)
... 1 more
```

Service Thread has stopped?!

Shorter version

```
package testServer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class driverServerTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        ServerSocket Ssc = new ServerSocket(21);
        Socket sc;
        sc = Ssc.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
        out.println("220 The connection succeeded");
        out.flush();
        String temp;
        while (true) {
            temp = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(temp);
            if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("AUTH SSL")) {
                out.println("334 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!");
                out.flush();
                SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
                sc = sslsocketfactory.createSocket(Ssc.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), Ssc.getLocalPort());
                ((SSLSocket) sc).setUseClientMode(false);

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((SSLSocket) sc).getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(((SSLSocket) sc).getOutputStream());
                out.println("234 request login information");
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Client response:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 ...
Status: Connected with 127.0.0.1, negotiating SSL connection...
Response:   220 The connection succeeded
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   334 Yo homie we can start that SSL connection!
```

Comment: Either you did not properly read the RFC or you've implemented it wrong. Since you don't show any code and don't show anything about your understanding of the RFC it is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: The code is unfortunately very long. Stand alone it is a FTP server without a secure connection. I read in the RFC that the Client should send an AUTH SSL to ask the server if it uses that protocol. and the reply should be  334. Then the client would start sending SSL messages through the socket. I just don't understand how the client can start sending those messages unless it has some sort of key distributed to it. In addition to the other vague spots.

Comment: The mechanism with `AUTH TLS` is the same you have with STARTTLS in SMTP, CONNECT in HTTP proxy etc: Client sends the request to upgrade the plain connection to TLS and server acknowledges this request. And after this the client starts the normal TLS handshake, i.e. the same as you do if you don't talk plain first. And of course the server needs to have certificate and key for this, same as with "normal" TLS you find in a web server.

Comment: @close-voters Please stop it. There is nothing off-topic or unclear about this question. If closed I will certainly vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with a plain `ServerSocket` and use `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, ...)` to upgrade the plain `Socket` to SSL if and when you receive the AUTH TLS command.

Don't forget to call `SSLSocket.setUseClientMode(false);` before you do any I/O with it.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I implemented that as under the Updated section that I just added to my original question and now get a strange string from the client. Is that the message that is encrypted and how do I decrypt it? I know I need a special keystore but how do I obtain and generate something like that?

Comment: How did you read the client response? You need to use the `SSLSocket,` and its input and output streams, for all future communication. I'm unclear about whether the 334 should be sent as plaintext or via SSL: probably the former.

Comment: I re stated my in buffer reader with the SSL Socket newly declared. Not sure if I am doing it right. Will tinker more. But, I am getting an error message saying : 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

I included my new updated in the original question above with code.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of your first sentence, and there isn't enough code in your question to verify whether you've followed my answer correctly.

Comment: I just added new code. I didn't say it very clearly but, what I meant was I had in reader and an out Print writer to read and print to the socket. I thought if I re declared it with the getoutputstream from the sslSocket, it might've fixed the problem. I added the code to the question above just now.

Comment: It says in [RFC 4217](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4217) that you should send 234, not 334, and in plaintext.

Comment: I made the whole code available at the bottom of my original post. Yes, I did the change from 334 to 234 but I still get the unrecognized ssl message exception at my code:
while ((this.clientMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
    svc = new ServerCmd(this.clientMessage);
    action(svc);
   }

Comment: You can't execute the code that is posted here. It is not complete. I can't help you further until you fix that. Nobody is going to chase links.

Comment: sadly Yeah, it is very difficult but I can post the whole code in the comments or at least try. The Whole program is separated into 6 class files with a credentials text file, config file, rolling log, and more.

I think I have to make a simpler program. Or find a way to safely post it.

Comment: **Don't post any code in comments.** It is illegible. Edit it into your question. Otherwise I will not even try to read it.

Comment: That is definitely true, code is eligible in comments. I am starting to think that it is crashing on the handshake. I'll post the entire stack trace in the original question. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Am starting to think that the handshaking procedure didn't occur correctly which lead to not being able to read the ssl message. Maybe. I don't know alot about this.

Comment: The client is still talking plaintext, as the exception message clearly says. Ergo you didn't send the 234 response correctly. The question is why.

Comment: I posted a log of the client and the server before the crash. It seems like the client did recieve the 234

Comment: As I said. So all we need is enough code to reproduce the problem. As I asked for many comments ago.

Comment: Ok I will make that now. Have to trim my code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem

Comment: But why the delay? Why all this fiddling around! Why not do as you are asked in the first place? You've just wasted an hour.

Comment: Sorry for the time wasted. I just re wrote a smaller version but, I can't reproduce the exact problem. Yet I still can't connect with SSL

Comment: I think if I can just get it to connect on the smaller model, implementing it into the large one would be possible. I just added the new shorter version into the bottom of my original question.

Comment: In the larger program, I noticed that when I switch to the SSLSocket connection, the original connection disconnects a bit so my original thread with the FTP service connected to the client drops and my other thread listening to the connections picks up the new SSLSocket connection and fires up another connection with the client. That is the one thing that the smaller model doesn't do.